# Assign SELECT to variable in SQL-Commander from DBVisualizer

Tags: sql-server, variable-assignment

I need to assign a select to a local variable. I already googled a lot and came to the following solution (which is not working, so it's not really a solution):

```
select @identId = (select ident_id FROM tablename WHERE number='0000001670');
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 936, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00936: missing expression.
```

A SET does not do the trick either. I tried as well DEFINE, but without any success as well. I need to assign this select to a variable, because i am going to delete this table and i need the value later on. On the other hand does it reduce my code duplication.

Does it have to look something like this:

```
select ident_id as identId FROM zam_partnerdublette WHERE pa_nummer='0000001670';
```

But then I can't use the variable later. I tried:

```
delete from tablename where ident_id=@identId;
delete from tablename  where ident_id=&identId;
delete from tablename  where ident_id=identId;
```

But all of them resulted in different errors:

```
[DELETE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 936, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00936: missing expression
[DELETE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 1008, SQL State: 72000]  ORA-01008: Not every variable has an assigned value
[DELETE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 904, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00904: "IDENTID": unknown identifier
```

Comment: Is this orcale or sql server, that error `ORA-00936` looks like an oracle error? http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00936.php

Comment: @Tanner Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT @identId = ident_id FROM tablename WHERE number='0000001670';
```

That's the SQL Server way, based on the tag you have included on the question. If it is Oracle that you're using, based on the error codes in your post, you would do this:

```
DECLARE @identId NUMBER;
SELECT ident_id INTO @identId FROM tablename WHERE number='0000001670';
```

Comment: With select @identId = ident_id FROM tablename WHERE number='0000001670'; i get the following error: [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 936, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: @Chris311 is it an oracle source? have you tried the second option?

Comment: Yes, the second solution delivers the following error: [DECLARE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: Row 1, Column 9:
PLS-00103: Found symbol "@" which is expected as one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
 09:56:24  [SELECT - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 936, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: can you try by removing the `@` symbol from the declaration of `@identId` and parameter in the `select into`?

Comment: I reduced the problem and only executed the first line. DECLARE @identId varchar2(12); results in error: [DECLARE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: Row 1, Column 9:
PLS-00103: Found symbol "@" which is expected as one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>
   <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete
   exists prior
symbol "@" was ignored.
ORA-06550: Row 1, Column 29:
PLS-00103: Found symbol "end-of-file" expected as one of the following:

   := ; not null default character

Comment: Without '@': results in error: [DECLARE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: 6550, SQL State: 65000]  ORA-06550: Row 1, Column 28:
PLS-00103: Found symbol "end-of-file" expected as one of the following:

   := ; not null default character

Comment: I couldn't make this work, which aligns with the comments.  I'm very confused.  If this didn't work, why is it marked as the correct answer?

Answer (score 1):

DBVisualizer is very particular about its variables.
You have to use something like this:

```
--/
your tsql;
/
```

It makes it very hard to intermix DBVisualizer variables with SQL variables.
See this and this:
https://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG130/Using+DbVisualizer+Variables
https://confluence.dbvis.com/display/UG130/Executing+Complex+Statements